# How to install VM from ISO?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, iso-image, qemu, libvirt

I prepared pool, volume and installation ISO, want to install headless VM using console. Here's my command:

```
virt-install -n myvm -r 2048 --disk path=/home/username/virtpools/mydisk.img
--location /opt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso
--graphics=none --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" 
--noautoconsole --network=bridge:virbr0
--controller=scsi,model=virtio-scsi
--disk path=$HOME/virtpools/mydisk.img,format=qcow2
```

It gives the following message:

```
Starting install...
mount: only root can use "--options" option
ERROR    Invalid install location: Mounting location '/opt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso' failed
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
```

My `/opt` `/opt/images` and ISO in the last directory are both readable and writable by world.

How one could solve that issue?
I think it's something(distro-specific) related to permissions users, etc.. I didn't figure it out yet.
Ubuntu 16.04

**EDIT**: When I(without `sudo`) specify URL in --location like http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/, it creates VM, so that I could login into it using `virsh console vm`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages seem to tell the story.

"mount: only root can use "--options" option" - add a sudo in front of your command (or use sudo su first to switch to root). There's multiple things that could have failed - most of the libvirt related tools need elevated permissions anyway.

Comment: It works with sudo. To me it seems like ugly solution, because I already added my user to `libvirtd` group to manipulate machines from non-root. Also I created and run machines via VNC using virt-manager, it worked without sudo. Please, see my edit about web URL.

Comment: And I didn't have passed --option switch.

Comment: *You* didn't. My guess is virt-install uses mount on the host to mount the ISO for the VM internally.

Comment: Did you log out and back in after adding yourself to the group? (this means coming completely out of X).

Comment: @djsmiley2k, I added my non-root to libvirtd many days ago, yes.
It seems that the problem is that virt-install cannot mount ISO without root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use `--cdrom` instead of `--location`.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-install

Comment: This answer would be better if you *quoted* what the man page says about ```--cdrom``` and ```--location```.